# Getting value from Go channel

Tags: select, tcp, go, nonblocking, channel

I have a go-routine which is listening for TCP connections and send these on a channel back to the main loop. The reason I'm doing this in a go-routine is to make this listening non-blocking and be able to handle active connections simultaneously.

I have implemented this with a select statement with an empty default case like this:

```
go pollTcpConnections(listener, rawConnections)

for {
    // Check for new connections (non-blocking)
    select {
    case tcpConn := <-rawConnections:
        currentCon := NewClientConnection()
        pendingConnections.PushBack(currentCon)
        fmt.Println(currentCon)
        go currentCon.Routine(tcpConn)
    default:
    }
   // ... handle active connections
}
```

Here is my pollTcpConnections routine:

```
func pollTcpConnections(listener net.Listener, rawConnections chan net.Conn) {
  for {
    conn, err := listener.Accept()  // this blocks, afaik
    if(err != nil) {
        checkError(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("New connection")
    rawConnections<-conn
  }
}
```

The problem is that I never recieve these connections. If I do it in a blocking way, like this:

```
for {
    tcpConn := <-rawConnections
// ...
}
```

I recieve the connections, but it blocks... I have tried buffering the channel as well, but the same thing happens. What am I missing here?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633373/how-to-do-nothing-when-no-channel-is-ready-to-be-read) for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a little hard to tell why you're not seeing any connections based on the existing code.  One problem with your sample is that you have an empty `default` case in a `select` statement, and then we can't see what else is happening in this `for` loop.  The way you've written it, that loop might never yield to the scheduler.  You're basically saying "get a thing from the channel.  don't have one?  ok, start over.  get a thing from the channel!", but you never actually wait.  When you do some action that blocks your goroutine, that goroutine yields to the scheduler.  So when you do a channel read in the normal fashion, if there's no value to be read, that goroutine is blocked reading.  Since it's blocked, it also yields to the scheduler to allow other goroutines to continue executing on the underlying thread.  I'm fairly certain this is why your `select` with an empty `default` is breaking; you're causing that goroutine to loop infinitely on the `for` loop without ever yielding to the scheduler.

It's not clear what the role of `pendingConnections` is, or whether it's needed at all.

The other thing that's impossible to tell from the behavior is what your `checkError` function does.  It doesn't, for example, continue to the top of the `for` loop, or bail.

Anyway, it looks like this is more complicated than it needs to be.  Just have a function that takes the new connection as it's one parameter, and then launch that in a new goroutine when it connects.  I always write it like this:

```
func handleConnection(c net.Conn) {
    // do something with your connection here.
}

for {
    // Wait for a connection.
    conn, err := l.Accept()
    if err != nil {
        // do something with your error.  You probably want to break or return here.
        break
    }
    // handle each connection in a new goroutine
    go handleConnection(conn)
}
```

this is more or less exactly what they do in [the documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#Listener).

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Tom pointed me to another question which had the same problem. Adding a runtime.Gosched() "fixed" the issue, but I understand that this probably means that my design is bad.

Your example is OK, except for that l.Accept() blocks. I want to continue doing stuff in the same loop.